# Importing files from different folders in React.js - Relative Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React.js, I struggle with relative paths...

Structure of the project,

```
-Project
    -node_modules
    -public
        -index.html
    -src
        -p1
            -test.json
        -give.js
        -loan.png
```

I like to import `test.json` file in `give.js` file, How to achieve this,

I tried this format - `import test from "./p1/test.json"` but it shows error - `Module not found`

And, I have a doubt, saving media files in public folder is safe or not?, Any hint would be very help full

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one way to solve this is to use require.

```
const test = require("./p1/test.json");
```

An alternate approach could be changing your JSON file to a js file, and exporting an object.

in p1/test.js

```
const test = { your JSON };
export default test;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your import statement, you are doing it just fine. The problem is probably with the file type.

You are trying to import a `JSON` file. Which will not work out of the box with react.

To fix this, convert your `.json` file to a `.js` with the structure like so:

**test.js**

```
export default { foo: 'bar' }
```

**give.js**

```
import test from "./p1/test"
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative path you've mentioned is correct.
Rather than using the file type of `.json`, use `.js` file extension.

And also make sure that you're exporting the data from your `test.js` file correctly. For eg.

#### test.js

```js
    export default const test = {
       "test": 1
    }
```

#### give.js

```js
   import test from './p1/test'
```

Saving media files in the public folder is acceptable but we save them in the src folder so that the build system can cache them, which leads to improvement in the performance of the app.